# After rebooting phone, app shortcuts from sd go missing

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, reboot, home-screen-shortcuts, stock-android, samsung-galaxy-s-advance

I own a Samsung Galaxy S Advance (i9070) with stock android 4.1.2

There is not a lot of internal storage, so I tend to move all possible apps from phone to SD card. However, when I reboot the phone, the shortcuts from the homescreen dissapear and i have to put them back in place all over again. Very annoying.

How can I fix this behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

So I have found a great solution. Using a micro SD-Card with 2 partitions. One normal fat32 and second ext2 so the app link2sd can use it as a fake mobile memory on the second ext2 partition. Now all the Jelly Bean internal apps run on the mobile itself and all the other apps I have installed on the second sd-card partition. Have more apps than ever and still over 150mb left on the mobile. GREAT. And the great side effect is, that all the shortcuts and widgets of other apps now work perfectly and dont disappear after reboot. YES!

Comment: It's worth noting that this work-around requires a rooted device.